# How to connect to MicrosoftTeams with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to connect to MicrososftTeams through powershell (using orchestrator). Here is my code

```
#get credentials 
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$adminName ="admin@admin.com"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminName , $pass 

#import module
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams 
write-output "credentialUsername : $cred.UserName"

#connect to microsoftTeams 
$conn = Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred -AccountId $adminName 

$team = get-team

write-output "connection:  $conn ; team: $team"
```

The last output return the $conn and $team empty. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems correct. please check if you have permissions.
if yes then check if this works.

```
$credentials = Get-credentials
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credentials
$team = get-team
write-host "$($team)" -ForegroundColor green
```